# Query in Firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-dataflow

What will be the Indexing and query for this in Firebase real-time Database?

[image: database]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I want to see how can we write query for this?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a way to sort and query on that params:

```js
var ref = firebase
  .database()
  .ref("indraday/2021-08-29")
  .orderByChild("AAMRANET/cp")
  .startAt("0.00");

ref.once("value", (snap) => {
  snap.forEach((childSnap) => {
    var childKey = childSnap.key;
    var childData = childSnap.val();
    console.log(childData);
  });
});
```

Do consider that you save the value as `String` and not as number. That means it will be sorted as if it is a `String` and not a number.